# Mathematica: setting "SetDirectory" to a remote server?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I set "SetDirectory" to a remote server with Mathematica?

I have tried SetDirectory["//server/folder/"] but without success. I also tried putting "smb:" before the // but it doesn't work. I get:

SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory

Looked at the documentation, but could not find help. Any suggestion? The server is password protected. I was expecting a username/password pop-up window, and I wonder if it's possible to set that up.

Thanks

Comment: If it's password-protected, it seems there is no way around. (Or maybe I can't find it)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way: I leave the Mathematica notebook file within the remote directory instead. That way I only have to go through password protection once.